# Use modern features like SURF in camera tracking?

Tags: camera, tracking

There are plenty of modern and effective features, which are suitable for camera tracking, like [SURF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF). Does blender use them? Apparently not, because it's camera tracking feature requires a lot of by-hand operations.

Is it possible to use that modern features in blender? Probably licensing prevents this, but may be there is some workaround for the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender currently uses a KLT-Tracker [(Kanade–Lucas–Tomasi)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanade%E2%80%93Lucas%E2%80%93Tomasi_feature_tracker) which is documented [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Motion_Tracking) .

While algorithms like [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) and SURF are patented, [ORB (Oriented Brief)](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html) could be an alternative (BSD licensed) it was developed in 2011 and is already implemented in [openCV](http://opencv.org/)

- [ORB](http://www.vision.cs.chubu.ac.jp/CV-R/pdf/Rublee_iccv2011.pdf)

I have no idea whether there are plans to use other algorithms in Blender.