# How do I reduce the sensitivity of the SURF feature detector?

Tags: tracking

I am using libmv, Blender's structure from motion library. The SURF feature detector is running a little wild on me, detecting over 7000 feature points on a relatively small image. I would like to reduce this sensitivity by providing a threshold of some sort. For example, opencv's SURF detection accepts a hessian minimum threshold parameter.

Can anyone guide me to improving my feature detection?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13419/use-modern-features-like-surf-in-camera-tracking